# Proxy pattern in Python

Tags: python, proxy-pattern

I have a lots of class implemented in my code. Now I realise that for each method invoked for all these classes I need to add a line:

```
with service as object:
```

So I'm trying to use the Proxy pattern to automatically do the job, this is my example code

```
class A(object):
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
    def hello(self):
        print 'hello %s!' % (self.name)
    def __enter__(self):
        print 'Enter the function'
        return self
    def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_value, traceback):
        print 'Exit the function'
class Proxy(object):
    def __init__(self, object_a):
#        object.__setattr__(self, '_object_a', object_a)
        self._object_a = object_a

    def __getattribute__(self, name):
        service = object.__getattribute__(self, '_object_a')
        with service as service:
            result = getattr(service, name)
        return result    

if __name__=='__main__':
    a1 = A('A1')
    b = Proxy(a1)
    b.hello()
    a2 = A('A2')
    b = Proxy(a2)
    b.hello()
```

Everything works find, I have the output:

```
Enter the function A1
Exit the function A1
hello A1!
Enter the function A2
Exit the function A2
hello A2!
```

But this is not exactly I need, because what I need is the equivalent of:

```
with a1 as a1:
    a1.hello()
```

And I must have the output:

```
Enter the function A1
hello A1!
Exit the function A1
Enter the function A2
hello A2!
Exit the function A2
```

What i need to have that result?
Thanks

Comment: That example does not work for me: `'NoneType' object has no attribute 'hello'`.

Comment: I don't know what you think `with a1 as a1` is supposed to mean, but it certainly doesn't make any sense here.

Comment: I think your `__enter__` should return `self`…

Comment: Yes my mistake, I've added return self to the code, thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I would use a decorator:

```
class Proxy(object):
    def __init__(self, object_a):
        self._object_a = object_a

    def decorateEnterExit(self, obj, f):
        def inner(*args, **kwargs):
            with obj as _:
                return f(*args, **kwargs)
        return inner

    def __getattribute__(self, name):
        obj = object.__getattribute__(self, '_object_a')
        dee = object.__getattribute__(self, 'decorateEnterExit')
        return dee(obj, getattr(obj, name))
```

That way the with will be only evaluated when the function is executed. The way you did it it would first evaluate the with (including exiting it) and then the *function* would be returned to be called. Now we return a function which will itself enter the with and call the function inside.

```
>>> Proxy(A('Ax')).hello()
Enter the function
hello Ax!
Exit the function
```

Note that you need to return `self` in your `__enter__` method of `A`:

```
def __enter__(self):
    print 'Enter the function'
    return self
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a return statement in your `__enter__` method, which should return an instance of your class(`self`).

As about the question, in your `Proxy`, it is likely, that result is evaluated after the context is closed. Try this to see what you actually return - is a bound method:

```
def __getattribute__(self, name):
    service = object.__getattribute__(self, '_object_a')
    with service as service:
        result = getattr(service, name)
        print result
    return result
```

this will show

```
Enter the function
<bound method A.hello of <__main__.A object at 0x022A2950>>
Exit the function
```

And only then method is called, after `__getattribute__` has returned it.